# Query is not running in CI 3.0.6

Tags: php

```
public function insert_success()
{
    $a=$this->input->post('n1');
    $b=$this->input->post('n2');
    $c=$this->input->post('n3');
    echo $a.$b.$c;  
    $sql="insert into register (name,password,email)
                            values('$a', '$b' , '$c' )";    
    $qr=$this->db->simple_query($sql);

    return true;
}
```

I am doing this in CI 3.0.6 version, and on line 15 it is showing an error:

> Call to a member function simple_query() on null in C:\Xamp\htdocs\MVC1\application\models\abc.php on line 15...

Please help me out...

Comment: What's line 15 in `C:\Xamp\htdocs\MVC1\application\models\abc.php`?

Comment: $qr=$this->db->simple_query($sql);

Comment: Sounds like your database `$this->db` isn't properly set.

Comment: at first i am doing like this...$qr=$this->db->query("insert into register (name,password,email)
                       values('$a', '$b' , '$c' )");

Comment: Maybe this link will help? https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html

Comment: thank you my friend ....you have saved me...

Comment: my database was not properly set.....thanks ......i am fighting for this from last 4hours ....

Comment: No problem! I posted an answer so that other people googling this issue can be helped as well! Since it helped you, feel free to upvote it / accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your database `$this->db` isn't properly set.

In order to set it properly, check out this [CI user guide](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html) on properly connecting to your database.